# How to determine if a user is a moderator or not?

Tags: support, moderators

I am just wondering that how do I know if a user is a moderator or not? Is there any flag or mark so, I can determine that is user moderator?

Comment: Check the "♦" Diamond.

Comment: Is it sheer coincidence that the topmost related question on the right is: _Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?_

Comment: @devnull it's not. I've got "FAQ for Stack Exchange sites"

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators *"Site moderators are distinguished from normal users by the diamond (♦) displayed beside their user names."*

Comment: It's worth noting however that high rep users have powers akin to a demi-moderator (such as voting to delete questions and answers, approving edits, voting to close etc)

Comment: @AlE. How do you say it is a duplicate question if you don't know that user with special mark(♦) is moderator. I have specified that **Is there any flag or mark to determine is user moderator?**. The linked question is about what is the role of moderator and what are the privileges assign to that moderator.

Comment: @AlE I agree with OP here, it's not really a dupe this time.

Comment: This info is definitely in the FAQ, and I thought it was covered in the introductory pages when you first sign up, no?

Comment: "Who are the **diamond** moderators, and what is their role?" -- dupe question title contains an answer, and the opening sentence answers this question: "Some people have a diamond after their username (ex: Jeff Atwood♦)..."

Comment: **"Who are the diamond moderators?"** that means there other type of moderators available who have different symbols? Am I right @gnat? This question confusing me. Do you have any other question where can i get answer like **"User name with ♦ symbol is moderator.**.

Comment: There aren't other types of moderators with other symbols @Nimesh. Though not everyone with a diamond is an elected moderator. Oded for example (who answered your question here) is a developer. And there are several Community Managers as well, who also have a diamond. To find elected moderators of a site, go to the users page and then the moderator tab: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: +1 for **Though not everyone with a diamond is an elected moderator.**. @Bart before asking this question i have also looked at dupe question. But, It was confusing me because in the whole question **diamond moderator** keyword has been used. That's why i have asked this question. Thanks Bart form more information.

Comment: Guys, If you thinks this question is duplicate then you can vote this question for delete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All moderators have a diamond next to their name.

Additionally, if you go to the users page, there is a moderators tab that will tell you exactly who is a moderator.

For Meta StackOverflow:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

---

The API has methods to fetch all moderators (includes employees) and elected moderators:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderators

And:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/elected-moderators

Comment: Now don't ask why Oded is not listed in the moderators tab of Meta SO.

Comment: I feel like Oded could fix that if Oded wanted. :-)

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any flag or mark ?

Each user who is moderator on any site has special symbol besides his profile name, which is "♦" diamond.